# Phonegap lawnchair adaptors

Tags: cordova, local-storage, lawnchair

Which adaptor should I use in phonegap to get coverage in maximum android and iOS devices? And other than providing cloud storage for the app, what is a good option to backup the data in case the lawnchair localstorage data somehow goes missing or corrupt, if the phongap file Api a good option?